# If data = 0 then do not update(execute) table. (JavaScript/SQL)

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, cordova

I only want the update query to be executed if the "VacantSpaces" is not 0. So in other words, once there is no longer any spaces for a specific event "VacantSpaces" will be 0 so the idea is that users should not be able to join and the number will not go -1, -2 etc.

However I am not quite sure how to go about this.

JavaScript Function:

```
function updateEvent(title) {
    db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("Update EventSoccer SET VacantSpaces = VacantSpaces -1, NoPeople = NoPeople + 1 
                       WHERE Title = '" + title + "'", 
                       [], 
                       successJoin,
                       errorCB
        );
    });

    function successJoin() {
        navigator.notification.alert("You have joined the event!",
                                      null, 
                                      "Information", "ok");

        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page4" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing the query like this:

```
tx.executeSql("Update EventSoccer SET VacantSpaces = VacantSpaces -1, NoPeople = NoPeople + 1 
               WHERE Title = '" + title + "' AND VacantSpaces > 0", 
               [], 
               successJoin,
               errorCB
);
```

NB: Please use the empty array `[]` you pass to the function as second parameter to sanitise your inputs.

Comment: Thanks mate, "AND VacantSpaces > 0" worked a treat. However, you forgot to have the double quote after the 0.

Comment: Although the database is no longer updated when VacantSpaces is 0, how can I alert the user that they cannot join from the above code because at the moment the success alert is still appearing?

Comment: You're right, I've fixed the quotes..

To achieve this you should be use a separated query or assuming that if this the query returns an empty object there's either an invalid `title` or the `VacantSpaces` is 0

Since you're doing an `UPDATE` query you cannot retrieve datas